# Internal 500 Error - home.html cannot be found

Tags: python, html, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a website with Heroku. However, I get a 500 internal error. Upon inspection, it seems that the main page "home.html" cannot be located. However, when I check the website locally, it works fine. What could be wrong here?

Here's a chunk of the error log detailing my issue:

```
raise TemplateNotFound(template)
2021-02-27T15:50:34.531564+00:00 app[web.1]: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html 

[2021-02-27 15:50:34,526] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2021-02-27T15:50:34.531544+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-02-27T15:50:34.531546+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2
```

Here's the python code used to deploy the website:

```
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/full library/')
def full_lib():
    return render_template("full library.html")

@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

@app.route('/results?')
def results():
    return render_template("results.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It's a simple app so far and works locally no issue. However, upon deployment, I get an error. I was getting an application issue before but I found it was a simple spelling mistake. I did also bring the files over from a different folder but they have been saved and checked over since.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a folder named `templates` ?

You have to place your template files (for example your "home.html") in this folder.

From the documentation (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/):

> Flask will look for templates in the templates folder. So if your
> application is a module, this folder is next to that module, if it’s a
> package it’s actually inside your package:
>
> Case 1: a module:
>
> ```
> /application.py
> /templates
>     /hello.html
> ```
>
> Case 2: a package:
>
> ```
> /application
>     /__init__.py
>     /templates
>         /hello.html
> ```

Comment: I do but I've called it Templates not templates, I'm wondering if the captial letter is causing issues. I'll check now  -edit: it didn't cause a change, still getting the 500 internal error

Comment: Ah OK. I think that you created this project on Windows ? But the OS used by heroku (a Linux) is case sensitive with files (template != Templates), that probably explains why it was working on your machine but not when deployed on heroku.

Comment: Yes I did use windows so it could be that. Since the code I have is so simple, I may just restart, carefully check my spellings and deploy new versions frequently to avoid errors. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I realised that Heroku wasn't detecting the change to the title of the folder, so I did a long way around deletion-reapply and it fixed it! The website is finally up, thank you for pointing out this issue, I'll be sure to be more careful next time

Comment: Glad all is OK for you!